# PHP output is not getting displayed

Tags: php

I'm new learning php, but i'm stuck in the very beginning .
Whatever method I try in PHP but I could not display variable data in output..
below is code which is copy pasted from internet, even in that I cannot see output of 
$username...pls help me!

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hi Jacob</h1>
<h3>Demonstrates using a variable</h3>
<?php
$userName = "Jacob";
print Hi, $userName;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In output it `" Hi, $username "` is getting displayed. not the data of variable

Comment: Did you give the file a `.php` extension? Are you running this from WWW or local computer? Is PHP installed, the list goes on...

Comment: @Fred-ii- We need a canonical duplicate to reference for these - it happens multiple times a day.

Comment: try this , `print 'Hi ' . $userName;`

Comment: ya i gave .php extension, i'm running from www. PHP is installed.

Comment: try echo('Hi'.$userName);

Comment: Please spend some time on a good PHP tutorial.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That one almost eluded me. It's almost 2 am here; I'm not at my sharpest at this time of night lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `print Hi, $userName;`

which should be

```
print "Hi,  $userName";
```

you need to wrap that line in quotes.

or concatenate (along with quotes)

```
print "Hi, " .$userName;
```

had you left out the `Hi,` and had done

```
print $userName;
```

would have printed `Jacob` so that's also acceptable.

any text needs to be wrapped in quotes.

---

This is also acceptable:

```
print 'Hi, ' .$userName;
```

but this

```
print 'Hi, $userName';
```

would print out `Hi, $userName` instead of the intended name assigned from the variable, so it's best to use double quotes when wrapping text and variables inside the same quotes.

Comment: i already [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775026/php-output-is-not-getting-displayed#comment36561462_23775026) this.

Comment: @user3358752 To close the question and marked as answered, tick the white checkmark till it turns Green. This is how the SO system works. Otherwise, your question will remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I saw what you did there, well played ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this one, Php Concatenation possible only with `dot(.)`. Also add the quotes around the string like `"Hi"`

```
print "Hi " . $userName;
```

instead of

```
print Hi, $userName;
```

Comment: Yeahhh, you totally missed the problem on this one.

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of way to print in php

```
print "Hi". $username;

print "Hi $username";

print "HI {$username}";
```

you can you anyone. you can also use echo to print you variable.

if you want to print array then you can use

```
print_r($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, Replace your PHP code with below...

```
<?php
   $userName = "Jacob";
   //print Hi, $userName;
   print "Hi, ".$userName;
?>
```

Note: For print any static content(string) you must use single or double "Quotation Marks". You can use ***print*** or ***echo*** keyword for displaying your code in PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this coe. It will must work.

```
echo "Hi, ". $userName;
```